# Sequence of digits hint

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many sequences of five digits (0-9) contain at least one 4 and at least one 7? Can someone give me a hint, I'm having trouble with this problem. The correct answer is 14,670 but I'm having trouble getting to that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Start with all the sequences, subtract those with no $4$, subtract those with no $7$, and notice you have subtracted those with neither a $4$ nor a $7$ twice, so add them back in once,

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Let $N$ be the number of all five-digit sequences.  Let $N_7$ be the number that do not contain a 7.  Let $N_4$ be the number of sequences that do not contain a  4.  Let $N_{47}$ be the number of sequences that contain neither a 4 nor a 7.  Use the inclusion-exclusion principle.